# Atomic transaction when using JDBC call after Hibernate processes

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jdbc, transactions

I get that code:

```
@Override
public void bulkInsert(Collection<SortingPlanData> data, SortingPlan plan) {
    Session session = getEntityManager().unwrap(Session.class);
    SessionFactoryImplementor sessionFactoryImplementation = (SessionFactoryImplementor) session
            .getSessionFactory();
    ConnectionProvider connectionProvider = sessionFactoryImplementation
            .getConnectionProvider();

    String sql = "insert into SORTING_PLAN_DATA (ACHEMINEMENT, ANCIEN_GROUPE_SERVICE_LABELS, BAG_ID, BARCODE_ID, CHRONOSERVICE, CODE_ROUTING, D_DEPOT_NUMBER, D_SORT, DELIVERY_STATION, DESCRIPTION, DESTINATION_PAYS_ALPHA2_ISO, DESTINATION_PAYS_ALPHA3_ISO, DESTINATION_PAYS_NUM_ISO,"
            + " DIST, GROUPE_SERVICE_LABELS, GROUPING_PRIORITY, LIVRAISON, O_SORT, ORIGINE_PAYS_ALPHA2_ISO, ROUTING_PLACES, S_SORT, SENDING_DATE, SERVICE_CODES, SITE_IATA, SORTING_PLAN_ID, TYPE_EXPORT, VILLE, ZIP_MAX, ZIP_MIN) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";

    Transaction tx = session.getTransaction();

    final int batchSize = 500;
    int count = 0;

    try {
        tx.begin();
        Connection con = connectionProvider.getConnection();
        PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(sql);

        for (SortingPlanData spd : data) {
            ps.setString(1, spd.getAcheminement());
            ps.setString(2, spd.getAncienGroupeServiceLabels());
            ps.setString(3, spd.getBagId());
            ps.setString(4, spd.getBarcodeId());
            ps.setString(5, spd.getChronoservice());
            ps.setString(6, spd.getCodeRouting());
            ps.setString(7, spd.getDDepotNumber());
            ps.setString(8, spd.getDSort());
            ps.setString(9, spd.getDeliveryStation());
            ps.setString(10, spd.getDescription());
            ps.setString(11, spd.getDestinationPaysAlpha2Iso());
            ps.setString(12, spd.getDestinationPaysAlpha3Iso());
            ps.setInt(13, spd.getDestinationPaysNumIso());
            ps.setString(14, spd.getDist());
            ps.setString(15, spd.getGroupeServiceLabels());
            ps.setString(16, spd.getGroupingPriority());
            ps.setString(17, spd.getLivraison());
            ps.setString(18, spd.getOSort());
            ps.setString(19, spd.getOriginePaysAlpha2Iso());
            ps.setString(20, spd.getRoutingPlaces());
            ps.setString(21, spd.getSSort());
            ps.setDate(22, new java.sql.Date(System.currentTimeMillis()));
            ps.setString(23, spd.getServiceCodes());
            ps.setString(24, spd.getSiteIata());
            ps.setLong(25, plan.getId());
            ps.setString(26, spd.getTypeExport());
            ps.setString(27, spd.getVille());
            ps.setString(28, spd.getZipMin());
            ps.setString(29, spd.getZipMax());

            ps.addBatch();

            count++;

            if (count % batchSize == 0) {
                ps.executeBatch();
                LOGGER.info(count + " lines inserted do far in");
            }
        }

        ps.executeBatch(); // insert remaining records
        ps.close();
        con.close();

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        tx.rollback();
        throw new HibernateException(e.getMessage(), e.getCause());
    }

    tx.commit();
}
```

The bulkInsert method is called from a class which itself is annotated with @Transactional, and of course, I get an Exception on `tx.begin()`:

```
org.hibernate.TransactionException: nested transactions not supported
```

Problem is, I have no idea on how to retrieve the existing transaction and transmit it to my `bulkInsert()` method. Any leads?

I'm using Java 6, with Hibernate 4, Spring 3.2.3 on a Sybase 15.5 database.

Comment: You are making it way to complex. Use a `JdbcTemplate` which uses the same `DataSource` as your `EntityManagerFactory` and it will automatically participate in the same transaction, next to that it greatly simplifies your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are making it way to complex, use a `[JdbcTemplate][1]` which uses the same `DataSource`as your `EntityManagerFactory`. This will obtain the current connection and automatically participate in the already ongoing transaction. Next to that it will greatly simplify your code.

```
@Autowired
private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate

@Override
public void bulkInsert(Collection<SortingPlanData> data, SortingPlan plan) {
    String sql = "insert into SORTING_PLAN_DATA (ACHEMINEMENT, ANCIEN_GROUPE_SERVICE_LABELS, BAG_ID, BARCODE_ID, CHRONOSERVICE, CODE_ROUTING, D_DEPOT_NUMBER, D_SORT, DELIVERY_STATION, DESCRIPTION, DESTINATION_PAYS_ALPHA2_ISO, DESTINATION_PAYS_ALPHA3_ISO, DESTINATION_PAYS_NUM_ISO,"
            + " DIST, GROUPE_SERVICE_LABELS, GROUPING_PRIORITY, LIVRAISON, O_SORT, ORIGINE_PAYS_ALPHA2_ISO, ROUTING_PLACES, S_SORT, SENDING_DATE, SERVICE_CODES, SITE_IATA, SORTING_PLAN_ID, TYPE_EXPORT, VILLE, ZIP_MAX, ZIP_MIN) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";

    jdbcTemplate.batchUpdate(sql, data, 500, new ParameterizedPreparedStatementSetter<SortingPlanData>() {
        public void setValues(PreparedStatement ps, SortingPlanData spd) throws SQLException {
            ps.setString(1, spd.getAcheminement());
            ps.setString(2, spd.getAncienGroupeServiceLabels());
            ps.setString(3, spd.getBagId());
            ps.setString(4, spd.getBarcodeId());
            ps.setString(5, spd.getChronoservice());
            ps.setString(6, spd.getCodeRouting());
            ps.setString(7, spd.getDDepotNumber());
            ps.setString(8, spd.getDSort());
            ps.setString(9, spd.getDeliveryStation());
            ps.setString(10, spd.getDescription());
            ps.setString(11, spd.getDestinationPaysAlpha2Iso());
            ps.setString(12, spd.getDestinationPaysAlpha3Iso());
            ps.setInt(13, spd.getDestinationPaysNumIso());
            ps.setString(14, spd.getDist());
            ps.setString(15, spd.getGroupeServiceLabels());
            ps.setString(16, spd.getGroupingPriority());
            ps.setString(17, spd.getLivraison());
            ps.setString(18, spd.getOSort());
            ps.setString(19, spd.getOriginePaysAlpha2Iso());
            ps.setString(20, spd.getRoutingPlaces());
            ps.setString(21, spd.getSSort());
            ps.setDate(22, new java.sql.Date(System.currentTimeMillis()));
            ps.setString(23, spd.getServiceCodes());
            ps.setString(24, spd.getSiteIata());
            ps.setLong(25, plan.getId());
            ps.setString(26, spd.getTypeExport());
            ps.setString(27, spd.getVille());
            ps.setString(28, spd.getZipMin());
            ps.setString(29, spd.getZipMax());
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Actually, I get a problem when inserting a huge amount of lines (more than 100 000) that way. My Sybase ASE RDBMS is protesting it has no more lock available, and is not inserting anything. Do you know anything about that?

Comment: Actually I have no idea, make sure that it executes under a single transaction and there might be something you could do in optimizing the reading. I'm to unfamilair with Sybase (is has been about 12 years or so that I last used it) to be helping you on that.